# Lodash: Sort array of objects prioritizing alphabets first followed by numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, lodash

I have an array of objects, let's say:

```
var objects = [
  {name: 'A'},
  {name: '1'},
  {name: 'B'}
]
```

Knowing that I can sort it using [Lodash sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#sortBy):

```
objects= _.sortBy(objects, 'name')
```

which will result in this:

```
[
  {name: '1'},
  {name: 'A'},
  {name: 'B'}
]
```

But my desired output is this:

```
[
  {name: 'A'},
  {name: 'B'},
  {name: '1'}
]
```

Please help.

Comment: @TrojanByAccident Yes what do you mean by same key? They are three different objects. And I'd showed what I have tried using Lodash soryBy, what do you mean by 'put some effort into it' when I posted what I have tried? Flagging your comment.

Comment: What's the possible range of characters? Only A-Z and 0-9?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes sir.

Comment: @user1422866 That's not exactly showing what you have tried. That's saying that you know something else doesn't give you the desired results, but you aren't showing any code of your own that attempts to achieve that result.

Comment: Are the name values only one character, or potentially more?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Potentially more but less than 20 characters.

Comment: @user1422866 is capitalization important? (e.g. do lowercase go before capitals)

Comment: When sorting the values `AA` and `A1`, which do you expect to come first? I.e., do your sorting rules only apply to the first character or also to subsequent characters?

Comment: Assuming (i) strings consist only of letters and digits (ii) sorting is case insensitive, the simplest solution is to transform the string to upper case and replace `0...9` (ascii 48...57) with `[...d` (ascii code 91...100) and compare using `==`, `>` and `<`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Array#sort` you can apply this logic:

```
// If both are numbers or both are not numbers
isNaN(a.name) === isNaN(b.name) ?
     // then compare between them 
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    : // else
    // If the 1st is not a number move it up, if it's a number move it down
    (isNaN(a.name) ? -1 : 1);
```

Without lodash:

```js
var objects = [{"name":"A"},{"name":"3"},{"name":"1"},{"name":"B"}];

objects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return isNaN(a.name) === isNaN(b.name) ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name) : (isNaN(a.name) ? -1 : 1);
});

console.log(objects);
```

As part of a lodash's chain:

```js
var objects = [{"name":"A"},{"name":"3"},{"name":"1"},{"name":"B"}];

var result = _(objects)
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return isNaN(a.name) === isNaN(b.name) ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name) : (isNaN(a.name) ? -1 : 1);
  }) 
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sort function must return 0 if both items are same. Results are unpredictable otherwise. Also, `isNaN` has odd behavior for `""`... `isNaN("") == isNaN("0")` is true.

Comment: @SalmanA - switched to `String@localeCompare`, it deals with both issues.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if using lodash's `sortBy` is the correct approach for this problem. Here's an implementation using Javascript's [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

It takes not only the first character but the entire string into account when doing the sorting.

```js
const objects = [{
  name: '2'
}, {
  name: 'B'
}, {
  name: '1'
}, {
  name: 'A'
}, {
  name: 'A1'
}, {
  name: 'AA'
}]

objects.sort((o1, o2) => {
  let a = o1.name, b = o2.name;
  let isDigit = x => x >= 48 && x <= 57;

  for (let i = 0, n = Math.min(a.length, b.length); i < n; i++) {
    let aCharCode = a.charCodeAt(i), bCharCode = b.charCodeAt(i);
    
    if (aCharCode !== bCharCode) {
      if (isDigit(aCharCode) && !isDigit(bCharCode)) return 1;
      if (isDigit(bCharCode) && !isDigit(aCharCode)) return -1;
      return aCharCode - bCharCode;
    }
  }

  return a.length - b.length;
});

console.log(objects)
```

For the given input, this prints out

```
[
  {
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "AA"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1"
  },
  {
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "name": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution with two `_.sortBy()`

One for priotizing alphabets first, then another one for sorting the elements.

In my opinion it's more readable and it will have no performance impact.

```js
const objects = [
  {name: 'B'},
  {name: '2'},
  {name: '1'},
  {name: 'A'}
]

const result = _.sortBy(_.sortBy(objects, o => !isNaN(parseInt(o.name)), 'name'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://lodash.com/vendor/cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This one too only takes the first character of the string into account. In the comments, OP stated that the strings can have up to 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

If `name` is an integer prefix it with `z` for comparison.

```js
var objects = [
  {name: 'z'},
  {name: 'A'},
  {name: '1'},
  {name: 'B'}
], sorted = _.sortBy( objects, [
        function(d) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(d.name))
                   && isFinite(d.name)
                       ? 'z' + d.name
                       : d.name;
        }
    ]
);
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://lodash.com/vendor/cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, but it only takes the first character of the string into account to do the comparison.

Comment: this will work as per the requirement described in the OP. that is, sort alphanumeric `name`s first, then by alpha second; ascending order. the string `A1` is considered a word (alphanumeric) and should be sorted as such. if this was not the original intent, OP'er should expand upon the requirements.

Comment: My interpretation obviously differs from yours, so clarification would indeed be helpful. Added a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Partition the input, sort separately and join back:

Code:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const customSort = (a) => _.chain(_.partition(a, i => isNaN(i.name))).flatMap(p => _.sortBy(p, 'name')).value();

const input = [
    { name: '1' },
    { name: 'A' },
    { name: '6' },
    { name: 'B' },
    { name: 'a' },
    { name: '0' },
    { name: '3' }];

console.log(customSort(input));
```

Output:

```
[ { name: 'A' },
  { name: 'B' },
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: '0' },
  { name: '1' },
  { name: '3' },
  { name: '6' } ]
```